# Why do different block animation constants have the same value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

UIViewAnimationOptions
Options for animating views with blocks.

```
enum {
   UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews            = 1 <<  0,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction      = 1 <<  1,
   UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState     = 1 <<  2,
   UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat                    = 1 <<  3,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse               = 1 <<  4,
   UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration = 1 <<  5,
   UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve    = 1 <<  6,
   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent      = 1 <<  7,
   UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews   = 1 <<  8,

   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut            = 0 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn               = 1 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut              = 2 << 16,
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear               = 3 << 16,

   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            = 0 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    = 1 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   = 2 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp          = 3 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown        = 4 << 20,
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAnimationOptions;
```

Consider the about enum definitions from the iOS documentation. 
My question is :
For UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut, the constant is "0 << 16", but if my understanding is correct, 0 left shift by 16 positions is still 0. And it should be the same as UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone which is "0 << 20" (since it should also be 0).  Having 2 very different options equal to the same value does not seem to make sense.

Also, my testing shows UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut does not seem to have any effect at all.

There could be some misunderstanding on my part, hope that somebody knowledgeable would help ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All options, that are equal to 0 are default settings, so if you dont pass in any option is the same as passing in `(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut| UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone)` or just `0`

Comment: I am still confused.. Is that specifying 'UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone' will render the animation behavior to be ease-in-and-out?

Comment: @Philip007, no. It means that for transitions (the effect for animating from one view to the other) the default is `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone`, as it is 0. and for the speed curve while animating `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` is the default, as it also is 0.

Comment: It make more sense to me now. So that we have two kinds of UIView animation: one is transition from one view to another, the other is moving one view, is it correct? If so, why put options of TWO kinds of animation in ONE enum?

Comment: They are different aspects of one animation: the effect (curl up , curl down, flip up, flip down) and the speed curve (ease in, ease out ease in & out, linear), and each aspect has a default. and this default is expressed by 0.

Comment: I guess that's why the enum is divided into 3 groups. Thank you!